# Converting original format of text processing file into PDF - using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python code for converting text to pdf. Instead of having fixed font size, alignment etc., I want to copy all the lines from the text file with original format(from text file). Is there a
way to get this logic using FPDF or any other method using python program?

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
pdf = FPDF() 
pdf.add_page() 
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 12) 
f = open("D:\hello.txt", "r") 
for x in f: 
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'L') 

pdf.output("D:\hello.pdf")
```

Comment: A plain text file contains no information about font size or alignment (except alignment done with additional spaces/tabs).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the data from the input file. Input file hello.txt can contain any text info(Ex: customer report). I want to copy all the text information(Report) into a new pdf(Ex: hello.pdf) with same style whereas I am passing the font name and size in the set_font().